# How to get Parse Result as Object format(JSON) when using Xtext Web Integration

Tags: java, json, parsing, xtext

I'm learning to use [Xtext](https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/103_domainmodelnextsteps.html)

In Unit Test, it has a function called `parseHelper.parse()` to get the Parse result as Object format:

```
@RunWith(XtextRunner)

@InjectWith(MyDslInjectorProvider)

class MyDslParsingTest {
@Inject
ParseHelper<Model> parseHelper

@Test
def void loadModel() {
    val result = parseHelper.parse('''
        Hello Xtext!
    ''')
    Assert.assertNotNull(result)
    Assert.assertTrue(result.eResource.errors.isEmpty)
}
}
```

I want to get the Parse result when integration with web so I add the following code to the file `/org.xtext.example.mydsl.web/xtend-gen/org/xtext/example/mydsl/web/MyDslServlet.java`

```
          MyDslParser myDslParser = new MyDslParser();
          CharSequence cs = "Hello Xtext!";
          IParseResult iParseResult = myDslParser.doParse(cs);
          log.info(iParseResult.getRootASTElement().toString());
```

Full code:

```
package org.xtext.example.mydsl.web;

import com.google.inject.Injector;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.eclipse.xtext.util.DisposableRegistry;
import org.eclipse.xtext.web.server.XtextServiceDispatcher;
import org.eclipse.xtext.web.servlet.XtextServlet;
import org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.lib.Exceptions;
import org.xtext.example.mydsl.web.MyDslWebSetup;
import org.eclipse.emf.common.util.URI;
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EObject;
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.Resource;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog;
import org.eclipse.xtend2.lib.StringConcatenation;
import org.eclipse.xtext.parser.antlr.*;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

import org.xtext.example.mydsl.myDsl.Model;
import org.xtext.example.mydsl.parser.antlr.MyDslParser;
import org.eclipse.xtext.parser.IParseResult;
import org.eclipse.xtext.parser.antlr.AbstractAntlrParser;
import org.eclipse.xtext.parser.ParseResult;
import org.eclipse.xtext.resource.XtextResource;
import org.eclipse.xtext.resource.XtextResourceSet;

/**
 * Deploy this class into a servlet container to enable DSL-specific services.
 */
@WebServlet(name = "XtextServices", urlPatterns = "/xtext-service/*")
@SuppressWarnings("all")
public class MyDslServlet extends XtextServlet {
  private DisposableRegistry disposableRegistry;
  final Slf4jLog log = new Slf4jLog("datpm");

  private static Pattern _pattern2 = Pattern.compile("/parser/(\\w+)");
  private XtextResourceSet resourceSet = new XtextResourceSet();

  @Override
  public void init() {
      log.info("init");
    try {
      super.init();
      final Injector injector = new MyDslWebSetup().createInjectorAndDoEMFRegistration();
      this.disposableRegistry = injector.<DisposableRegistry>getInstance(DisposableRegistry.class);
    } catch (Throwable _e) {
      throw Exceptions.sneakyThrow(_e);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void destroy() {
    if ((this.disposableRegistry != null)) {
      this.disposableRegistry.dispose();
      this.disposableRegistry = null;
    }
    super.destroy();
  }

  @Override
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
      String url =  req.getRequestURL().toString();
      Matcher _matcher = _pattern2.matcher(url);
      // parser
      if (_matcher.find()) {
          resp.setContentType("text/x-json");
          Gson gson = new Gson();
          MyDslParser myDslParser = new MyDslParser();
//        Reader reader = new StringReader("Hello Xtext!");
          CharSequence cs = "Hello Xtext!";

          IParseResult iParseResult = myDslParser.doParse(cs);

          log.info(iParseResult.getRootASTElement().toString());

          gson.toJson(iParseResult.getRootASTElement().toString(), resp.getWriter());         
      } else {
          XtextServiceDispatcher.ServiceDescriptor service = getService(req);
          if (!service.isHasConflict() && service.isHasSideEffects()) {
              super.doGet(req, resp);
          } else {
              doService(service, resp);
          }  
      } 
  }
}
```

When I run the `ServerLauncher.java` and access `http://localhost:8080/xtext-service/parser/aaaaaaaa` , it gives me this error:

```
[main] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.util.log - Logging initialized @91ms
[main] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - jetty-9.3.8.v20160314
[main] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.StandardDescriptorProcessor - NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
[main] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler - Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@3a5ed7a6{/,[file:///home/thangld_anm/eclipse-workspace/org.xtext.example.mydsl.parent/org.xtext.example.mydsl.web/WebRoot/, jar:file:///home/thangld_anm/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.webjars/requirejs/2.3.2/f70d2efec834af46229ffd92231acc18fa7856a/requirejs-2.3.2.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/thangld_anm/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.webjars/jquery/2.2.4/c3dc40b1b5f24c56afa36fd9a463bb9f378ac4ab/jquery-2.2.4.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/thangld_anm/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.eclipse.xtext/org.eclipse.xtext.web/2.12.0/b51418291a072d6c7520b0237e447cb30eb9b711/org.eclipse.xtext.web-2.12.0.jar!/META-INF/resources, jar:file:///home/thangld_anm/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.webjars/ace/1.2.3/c027fca9e205f9f4a6b154a725cf41dbeff21a89/ace-1.2.3.jar!/META-INF/resources],AVAILABLE}
[main] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector - Started ServerConnector@3cef309d{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{localhost:8080}
[main] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - Started @1960ms
[main] INFO org.xtext.example.mydsl.web.ServerLauncher - Server started http://localhost:8080/...
[Thread-11] INFO org.xtext.example.mydsl.web.ServerLauncher - Press enter to stop the server...
[qtp1558600329-10] INFO datpm - init
[qtp1558600329-10] WARN org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler - /xtext-service/parser/aaaaaaaa
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.xtext.parser.antlr.AbstractAntlrParser.parse(AbstractAntlrParser.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.parser.antlr.AbstractAntlrParser.doParse(AbstractAntlrParser.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.parser.antlr.AbstractAntlrParser.doParse(AbstractAntlrParser.java:70)
    at org.xtext.example.mydsl.web.MyDslServlet.doGet(MyDslServlet.java:87)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.web.servlet.XtextServlet.service(XtextServlet.java:60)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:837)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:583)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1160)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1092)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:518)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Can you tell me how to get the Parse result? Is IParseResult the right module to do the job? Thank you so much.

Comment: can you confirm that the code reaches MyDslServlet.java to the DoGet () method ??

Comment: @rohitthomas yes sir, right in the log `at org.xtext.example.mydsl.web.MyDslServlet.doGet(MyDslServlet.java:87)` . It reaches line `IParseResult iParseResult = myDslParser.doParse(cs);` ,gets error here and never reaches line `log.info(iParseResult.getRootASTElement().toString());`

Comment: Can you paste the code of MyDslParser  as I cant find it the document

Comment: @rohitthomas It is auto generated when you create project with following steps: `New Project` -> `Xtext Project` -> select `Create Feature` `Web integration` `Prefered build system: Gradle` -> `Finish` .

Comment: @rohitthomas I push the code to github anyway. https://github.com/thangld322/mydsl 
Link to the file you want: https://github.com/thangld322/mydsl/tree/master/org.xtext.example.mydsl/src-gen/org/xtext/example/mydsl/parser/antlr

Comment: Can you try the following IParseResult iParseResult = myDslParser.doParse(new ByteArrayInputStream(cs.getBytes())) Went through AbstractAntlrParser it in turns calls ANTLRReaderStream here is where you are getting the NULL issue is you don't find debugging it you will be able to find the issue

Comment: Let me know if the above works

Comment: Thanks for replying. It gets errors:

Multiple markers at this line
 - The method getBytes() is undefined for the type CharSequence
 - The method doParse(Reader) in the type AbstractAntlrParser is not applicable for the arguments 
  (ByteArrayInputStream)

Comment: Sorry can you change cs to String and try with Reader reader = new StringReader(s); -->AbstractAntlrParser  accepts only java.io.Reader and java.lang.CharSequence with single arguments